# How can I change option later after declining event?

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api

```
GET /me/messages/{longMessageId}?expand=microsoft.graph.eventMessage/event
```

This will return the event object in the mail.

Then I can use

```
POST /me/events/{longEventId}/accept
POST /me/events/{longEventId}/tentativelyAccept
POST /me/events/{longEventId}/decline
```

Once I **accept**, **tentativelyAccept**. I can still use

```
GET /me/messages/{longMessageId}?expand=microsoft.graph.eventMessage/event
```

to return the message object with event object.

However, if I **decline** it,

```
GET /me/messages/{longMessageId}?expand=microsoft.graph.eventMessage/event
```

will return the message object but with an empty event object `{}`.

So how can I change option later?

Answer (score 0):

That is correct. When you decline the event, it is removed from your calendar. Therefore, there is no event to expand.

Comment: Oh, thanks. The reason I asked this is because, for Outlook, once I decline the event. If I change my mind, I can still go to the trash folder, open the mail, and accept or tentativelyAccept again. Is there any other way to do it?